# Matrix for polynomial linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am looking to represent $T(f) = 2f + f'$ as a matrix $B$ with respect to the basis $\{1, 1+x, x^2\}$. I am used to this type of question only when the basis involves vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. My guess was to think of the basis $\{1, x, x^2\}$ in terms of the standard $\mathbb{R}^3$ basis.

So the 'change of basis' matrix would be

$C = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

and I found that $T(1) = 2(1)$; $T(x) = 1(1) + 2(x)$; $T(x^2) = 2(x) + 2(x^2)$. So according to my earlier guess, the matrix for T with respect to the basis $\{1, x, x^2\}$ is

$A = \begin{bmatrix}2&1&0\\0&2&2\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}$

Which gives me the answer

$B = C^{-1}AC = \begin{bmatrix}2&5&2\\0&2&2\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}$

Is this correct and do I have the right/wrong idea?

Comment: [Actually](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3499836/242) $3^{11}\not\equiv -1$ (typo), but still $3^{22}\equiv 1.\ $ I coudn't fix it because you deleted it. Also $\, 1541 = 23(67)\,$ is not prime.

Comment: If you undelete it I can show you a simple way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you have taken the conjugate correctly, as you should obtain
$$
B 
= 
C^{-1}AC 
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & -2\\
0 & 2 & 2\\
0 & 0& 2
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Let us check
$$
\begin{cases}
T(1) &= 2 \cdot 2 + 0 = 2,\\
T(1 + x) &= 2 (1 + x) + 1,\\
T(x^{2}) &= 2 x^{2} + 2 x = 2 x^{2} + 2 (1 + x) - 2 \cdot 1.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks, it was an error computing $C^{-1}AC$ on my part.

Comment: @AzamatBagatov, of course s*** happens. Note that you could have caught the error by also calculating the matrix directly, as above, and noting the the two answers did not match.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct.

You cound also solve the problem without a change-of -basis matrix. Just compute $T(1)$; it is $2$. Now, which are the coordinates of $1$ in the given basis? Since $2=2\times1+0\times(x+1)+0\times x^2$, they are $2$, $0$, and $0$. So, now you have the first column of your matrix. You'll get the second and the third columns if you do the same thing with $x+1$ and with $x^2$ respectively.